# Convert WPF project into MonoDevelop

Tags: c#, wpf, monodevelop

Is it possible to convert the WPF project code into MonoDevelop? I need to re-write wpf project into MonoDevelop for cross platform support.

Comment: Did you try anything?

Comment: Yes. I tried Dispatcher CommunicationDispatcher

Answer (score 3, accepted):

WPF is not supported by Mono, and will probably never be.

Because of that, even if you could somehow import your WPF project into MonoDevelop for Windows, it would not be of much use.

You will have to separate UI+WPF code from the rest of your application, and create the cross-platform UI with a different UI toolkit.

Comment: I want to re-write only WPF Code part not UI.

Answer (score 0):

A subset of WPF seems to be possible through Silverlight on Windows and MacOS X. If you want to run on Linux as well, Moonlight will probably run your Silverlight port.

Please see these two links:

- http://www.mono-project.com/WPF
- http://www.mono-project.com/Moonlight